# Disk Part there are no fixed disks to show

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am trying to install windows 7 on new HDD in window `where do u want to install windows ?`
it showed me a drive i deleted by mistakenly the drive as soon as it was done nothing is showing up and if i try to do it from `cmd`it is saying **there are no fixed disks to show.**

**`cmd code`**

1. Diskpart
2. list disk

my Machine is Dell Inspiron 600 an not sure what to do i did every thing that was possible need help

Comment: What happens if you start over with the install?

Comment: the same issue comes